# switching the order of the methods changes the result

Tags: javascript

the following will be the code

let a = 100;

let b = 2_00.5;

let c = 1e2;

let d = 2.4;

console.log(Math.min(Math.round(a, b, c, d)));

console.log(Math.round(Math.min(a, b, c, d)));

**

the wanted answer is 2.

with the first one, I get 100. How am I getting 100?

with the second one, I get the desired answer.

can someone explain this to me?

thanks

**

Comment: check how `Math.round` works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: This is fundamental mathematics. [Function composition](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) is, in general, not [commutative](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). `Math.round(a, b, c, d)` itself doesn’t make sense. It’s the same thing as `Math.round(a)`.

Comment: so do you mean that the code does not read from let to right in this case? meaning it starts from whatever in the () ? is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.round()` accepts just one argument, so arguments b,c,d are ignored in your first example; its the same as calling `Math.round(a)`

To change the order the functions are called:

```js
Math.round(Math.min(a, b, c, d))
```

is equivalent to

```js
Math.min(...[a,b,c,d].map(x => Math.round(x)))
```